# Accessing an object within another object in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I have an array output like this from drupal, how do I access the value of [name] from 
field_episode_tags, I have this so far

```
print $node->field_episode_tags['und']['0']['taxonomy_term']->['name']
```

When I get up to 'taxonomy term' there is another object i tried using another -> poitner but that did not work.

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [vid] => 25
        [uid] => 1
        [title] => Is there any cosmos theory?
        [log] => 
        [status] => 1
        [comment] => 1
        [promote] => 0
        [sticky] => 0
        [nid] => 25
        [type] => tv_episode
        [language] => en
        [created] => 1380610491
        [changed] => 1381115053
        [tnid] => 0
        [translate] => 0
        [revision_timestamp] => 1381115053
        [revision_uid] => 1
        [body] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [value] => summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text 
                                [summary] => 
                                [format] => filtered_html
                                [safe_value] => <p>summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text summary text</p>

                                [safe_summary] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

        [field_video_category] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [tid] => 25
                            )

                    )

            )

        [field_featured] => Array
            (
            )

        [field_kaltura_video] => Array
            (
            ) und 0 taxonomy term->name

        [field_episode_tags] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [tid] => 95
                                [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [tid] => 95
                                        [vid] => 1
                                        [name] => zen
                                        [description] => 
                                        [format] => 
                                        [weight] => 0
                                        [vocabulary_machine_name] => tags


                       [rdf_mapping] => Array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the instance datamember directly without the brackets []. These are used for array keys.

```
 print $node->field_episode_tags[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['taxonomy_term']->name
```